# Does flyway support AWS Timestream?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, time-series, flyway, amazon-timestream

Does anyone know if flyway supports migrations for AWS Timestream? I don't see Timestream in the docs as a supported database, but wanted to double check.

If not, can anyone suggest a CI/CD way to handle migrations for AWS Timestream?

Answer (score 1):

Flyway doesn't currently support Amazon Timestream:

[https://flywaydb.org/documentation/#:~:text=Supported%20databases%20are%20Oracle%2C%20SQL,Amazon%20RDS%2C%20Azure%20Database%2C%20Google](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/#:%7E:text=Supported%20databases%20are%20Oracle%2C%20SQL,Amazon%20RDS%2C%20Azure%20Database%2C%20Google)

You can use AWS Kinesis along with the Timestream Flink connector to move the data across. Here is a blog post that explains the process:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/creating-amazon-timestream-interpolated-views-using-amazon-kinesis-data-analytics-for-apache-flink/